# How can I do inverse selection in AdvStringGrid?

Tags: delphi, tms

How can I do inverse selection in AdvStringGrid (TMS)?

Comment: please put some effort into explaining what you mean

Comment: Something like this ? [disjunct cell selection](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg48.asp)

Comment: I think OP means he wants to inverse the selection. Is it really that hard to understand? +1

Comment: E.g. in a 1 by 4 grid in which cells 2 and 3 are currently selected, cells 1 and 4 have to be selected instead.

Comment: "**invert** selection" maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, that NGLN is right, you'll need to set the proper Disjunct...Select option in Grid.MouseActions to select the kind of selection you'll allow, and then you can call this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE InvertSelection(Grid : TAdvStringGrid);
  VAR
    C,R : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    IF Grid.MouseActions.DisjunctCellSelect THEN
      FOR R:=Grid.FixedRows TO PRED(Grid.RowCount) DO FOR C:=Grid.FixedCols TO PRED(Grid.ColCount) DO Grid.SelectedCells[C,R]:=NOT Grid.SelectedCells[C,R]
    ELSE IF Grid.MouseActions.DisjunctRowSelect THEN
      FOR R:=Grid.FixedRows TO PRED(Grid.RowCount) DO Grid.RowSelect[R]:=NOT Grid.RowSelect[R]
    ELSE IF Grid.MouseActions.DisjunctColSelect THEN
      FOR C:=Grid.FixedCols TO PRED(Grid.ColCount) DO Grid.ColSelect[C]:=NOT Grid.ColSelect[C]
  END;
```

This will make all unselected rows/columns/cells selected and vice-versa.

Comment: Sorry, but this function doesn't work. Do you try to use this code?

Comment: @YoungMaster, I've tested it and it works. You probably missed the part how to set the `MouseActions.DisjunctCellSelect` or `MouseActions.DisjunctRowSelect` or `MouseActions.DisjunctColSelect` property to `True` on your `TAdvStringGrid`. One of them must be set which allows you to select something else than rectangle. This is perfectly acceptable answer ;)